# NextJS 13 root.layout rendering NavBar at the bottom. Is there a way to consistently render NavBar at the top?

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js, routes, server-side-rendering

I'm experimenting building a Next13 app. The new layout is cool, but it is messing up the rendering. I don't entirely understand the ordering of rending objects within the layout:

Navbar.tsx

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";

export default () => {
  return (
    <span className="flex justify-between">
      <h1 className="text-xl">Navigation Bar</h1>
      <ul className="flex gap-4">
        <li>
          <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/user/login">Login</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/user/signup">Sign Up</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  );
};
```

layout.tsx

```
import "./globals.css";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html className="bg-slate-500 font-robslab" lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Stylitique</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </head>
      <header>
        <NavBar />
      </header>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

page.tsx (HOME)

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="text-green-500">HOME</h1>
      <p>
        {" "}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora
        sapiente, expedita praesentium a eligendi dolorem maiores nihil
        consectetur ipsum, repudiandae sed deserunt delectus, facere repellat
        ipsam sit possimus voluptatibus error!
      </p>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I tried:

1. putting the NavBar into a header outside the body.
2. putting it straight into the body.
3. with and without "use client".
4. added more data to "HOME" in order to render slower, I guess.

Anyone find a solution yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just put the component inside `<body>`

> **notice**: no need of `<header>`

```js
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <NavBar />
  {children}
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I just slapped my forehead pretty hard. Thanks.

Comment: can i add another layout for my dashboard routes ? i mean one layout for normal website page and and one for dashboard.